# How to set continuous scrolling in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am having four values in `ArrayList`. I have set the values for `ListView`. But I need to scroll the `ListView` again and again with that static four values(`ArrayList`) with selected list position. Now I couldn't scroll with four static values. If anyone knows answer kindly share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want the item at position 1 to also appear at 5, 9, 13, 17...etc, so that when you scroll past the last item in the list, it starts back over from the beginning?

Comment: @WajeEh.. Ya, I need to scroll from beginning after the value comes to last index.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) and then just keep inserting these 4 values every time `appendCachedData()` is called.